# This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us. magento (ship it)

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

i am using magento 1.9.3.1 , and i am using "[SHIPIT](https://www.shippit.com/)" for couriers and shipping calculation

But now i am getting error in checkout page . the error message is

> "This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to
>   ship using this shipping method, please contact us."

[image: exception]

[image: backrnd setting]

can any one suggest me how to solve this problem

Comment: same issues facing on magento 1.9.1.0 on table rates.

Comment: Any suggestions how to solve this? I got the very same issue...

Comment: Same with me, when i use coupons. Is there an update about this issue ?